# What is the parameter order of a quaternion constructor?

Tags: python

I cannot find the source code of mathutils, since it can be imported from python I assume it is a python source.

Essentially I want to find out whether a [quaternion](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_6/mathutils.html) is created with W,X,Y,Z fields or X,Y,Z,W.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can figure it out easily in the py console:

```
q = Quaternion((1,2,3,4))
print(q.w, q.x, q.y, q.z)
# -> 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0, so it's WXYZ
```

The mathutils module is not python source btw., the Quaternion class is written in C and located here:

> BlenderSVN\blender\source\blender\python\mathutils\mathutils_Quaternion.c

Comment: +1 for providing the answer *and* providing a good method for any similar questions.

Answer (score 4):

It's with (W,X,Y,Z). If you look in the documentation you linked, there is :

```
import mathutils
import math

# a new rotation 90 degrees about the Y axis
quat_a = mathutils.Quaternion((0.7071068, 0.0, 0.7071068, 0.0))
```

And, if you add a cube, set the rotation mode to `Quaternion`, then rotate it 90° on the Y axis, you can check :

[image]

The displayed values are in the same order. So you can deduce that it is **(W,X,Y,Z)**.